# PHP fixed time relative to GMT time

Tags: php, datetime

Using PHP I am trying to send one email to partners from different countries at specific time frame. Let us say that the hour is fixed to 17:00 to each country not to my time frame. So, if I am in London, the 17:00 hours will be different than Australia's 17:00 hours.

How can I check and make sure that for a list of countries the email sent is at the correct 17:00 hours?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You could write a script that is configured to run every 30 min (given some timezones are 30 min apart) via cron or something similar. This script will fetch the current timezone and calculate the difference with each country's timezone and figure out what time exists in each of the countries and if that is the time you want to send email to them. Dont forget to factor in DST

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine you're going to use a cronjob. If that's the case you can set the script to run every hour. When the script runs it should check in which timezone/country it's the desired hour. If a timezone/country is found to have the desired hour on that run, select the users from that timezone/country and send your email to them

Code to check time in AU:

```
$tz1 = new DateTimeZone('GMT');
$tz2 = new DateTimeZone("Australia/Sydney");
$date = new DateTime(null, $tz1);
$date->setTimezone($tz2);
$australia_hour = $date->format("H:i");
```

Comment: Yes, I will use cron jobs, but how can I verify if in Australia is 17:00 hours? I am  on GMT+0 and Australia is GMT+11h. Is any PHP function that can take care of the problem?

Comment: See https://php.net/manual/en/class.datetimezone.php and https://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php . You use DateTimeZone along with DateTime to convert a datetime from one timezone to another

Comment: Note that you may want to use `"H:00"` so that way you avoid minutes. Also, as mentioned by Neo a few countries use a wacked TZ. http://www.timeanddate.com/time/time-zones-interesting.html

Comment: If you supply the proper timezone literal to DateTimeZone it will take care about DST and stuff like that for you. I said hourly pooling just as an example. It depends on what TZ are you checking.

Comment: @rosuandreimihai: no need to create two DateTimezone objects, and no need for changing timezones, just initialize DateTime object with needed timezone, like this: `$date = new DateTime('now', new DateTimezone("Australia/Sydney"));`. [demo](https://eval.in/210227)